# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTE Remote Desktop

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu

I have been struggling with this for about two days now so I figured it’s times to ask you all for some help.

I’ve read a ton of different suggestions on how to enable Remote Desktop over Ubuntu but none of them have worked.

I’d prefer to use RDP, but any protocol/program that allows me to view my Ubuntu desktop remotely will work.

I’m connecting to a headless computer via an Ethernet cable. I’ve already set the static ip via /etc/network/interfaces and can successfully ping the machine.

Thanks in advance for any help!!

Comment: Have you looked into tightvnc?

Comment: RDC is a windows-only proprietary structure, nix & Mac use VNC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to consider [NoMachine](https://www.nomachine.com/), though it while it is 'freeware', it's not libre/open source if you care about that. I typically use this for no-hassle remote desktop admin. It's always an install-and-done thing for my usage. This uses the NX over SSH protocol, which is entirely different than RDP and VNC, but does the same thing. I find that it's faster and more responsive, which you may like better.

Also, if you are having issues with other RDP (which typically works as a VNC wrapper on Linux) or VNC applications, check if the `ufw` Ubuntu firewall is active with `$ sudo ufw status`. If it shows 'active'/'enabled', then that may be the cause, and you can try (security allowance permitting) to see if those applications work by disabling it with `$ sudo ufw disable`. If they then work, you can add those ports to the UFW firewall exclusions, and that would be your solution.

Comment: NoMachine worked perfectly! Thanks a ton. Wasted so much time with other programs. Really appreciate it

Comment: Hey awesome, glad to hear that worked for you